# Getting co-ordinates of marker in cemetery from satellite photograph

Tags: images, image-processing

maps.google.com offers this view of a local cemetery. What software might I use, preferably a Python library, that can approximate the locations of each of the cemetery markers (ie, the gravestones) and add them to a file? I understand that some of the markers are too small to be identified. However, even if I can get the co-ordinates of a just a large fraction of the markers that would be very helpful.

Thanks for your help.

[image: cemetery satellite view]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this article from Google Earth Help, [Find & use location coordinates](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148068?hl=en). I brought up Google map to display a local cemetery and then picked two different graves which generated two different locations.

[image: two different location lattidue and longitude of cemetary markers]

Also see this article, [how to look up coordinates of a point in new google maps?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/Ei5W6yeOTkM) which provides a bit more info.

I just zoomed in the satellite view of the cemetery until individual graves were visible and then picked them with the mouse such as in the screen shot.

[image: screen capture of Google Maps of cemetery getting location of a grave site]

What may work would be to get a screen shot at a particular resolution and to then mark specific calibration points whose location can be determined and then do a pixel by pixel scan of the screen shot image to interpolate the location of individual image features.

Then come back and do a spot check on specific features to see if the interpolation was reasonably sane.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using Google Earth. I wouldn't mind clicking on individual stones but then I would need a way of recording the co-ordinates automatically. I can probably work out to do that somehow.

Comment: @BillBell this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158474/how-to-obtain-longitude-and-latitude-for-a-street-address-programmatically-and

Comment: @BillBell also take a look at this video about the JavaScript API of Google Maps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zxf1mnP5zcw